# unable to pass form validation with proper values

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

i have made a directive which uses form validation if the mobile no already exists in service but it shows validation for every 10 digit no whether it exists or not.please tell me where i'm going wrong
here is my code.

HTML

```
 <div class="col-xs-8">
                        <md-input-container>
                            <md-icon md-svg-icon="assets/images/device.svg"></md-icon>
                            <input type="number" placeholder="Enter user mobile no" name="mobile" id="mobile" ng-model="mobile" required minlength="10"  ng-pattern="/^[789]\d{9}$/" phone-number-validator>
                                <div ng-messages="myForm.mobile.$error">
                                <div ng-message="required">Registered mobile no.</div>
                                    <div ng-message="phoneNumber">The mobile No entered has already been registered</div>
                                <div ng-message="test">too short</div>
                            </div>
                        </md-input-container>
                    </div>
```

here is my directive

```
angular.module('shoppingPad').directive('phoneNumberValidator',phoneNumberValidator)


function phoneNumberValidator($q,loginServices){
    //var deferred=$q.defer();
    return{
        restrict:'EA',
        require:'ngModel',

        link:function($scope,element,attrs,ngModel){
            ngModel.$asyncValidators.phoneNumber=function(modelValue , viewValue) {

                var mobile= (modelValue).toString();
                console.log(mobile);
                console.log("abc");

                    if(mobile.length == 10){

                        return $q(function(resolve,reject){
                            if(mobile==loginServices.getMobileNo.mobile1){
                                resolve();

                            }
                            else reject();
                        });

                }

            }
        }
```

here is my service from which im passing data

```
this.getMobileNo=function(){
        var mobile={
            mobile1:'8898246388',
            mobile2:'8898302454',
            mobile3:'8898454302'
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code wrong in two things:
this method getMobileNo must **return** object

```
this.getMobileNo=function(){
    return mobile={
        mobile1:'8898246388',
        mobile2:'8898302454',
        mobile3:'8898454302'
    }
 }
```

Then in calling to your service, need **()** for calling a function:
`if(mobile==loginServices.getMobileNo().mobile1){`

Comment: if im using (). it says Cannot read property 'mobile1' of undefined

Comment: Change your function also. a work version here: https://plnkr.co/edit/e7Dwyg?p=info

Comment: which function im not getting exactly because i see the same directive code in plunker also

Comment: As I said in the answer above, getMobileNo must return object. Your current code is not. or you can assign it directly with this.getMobileNo = {
        mobile1:'8898246388',
        mobile2:'8898302454',
        mobile3:'8898454302'
 }  and access with loginServices.getMobileNo.mobile1